# Mono and Array.Sort

Tags: c#, linux, mono, monodevelop

How can I use `Array.Sort(someArray)` in Mono with the Monodevelop !? I'm using Mono 4.2.2 and Monodevelop 5.10.

Did I has to import some namespace? Which one?

Is there another method to use?

I've been trying that and don't works:

```
var Color = new String[5];

Color[0] = "Orange";
Color[1] = "Blue";
Color[2] = "Purple";
Color[3] = "Green";
Color[4] = "Red";

Array.Sort(Color); //Error: The type or namespace name 'Sort' does not exist in namespace 'Array'. Are you missing an assembly reference?

Console.WriteLine ("Colors:");

foreach(string s in Color)
{
    Console.WriteLine (s);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array` is in the `System` namespace and is included within `mscorlib` (Mono/.Net 2/4/4.5+).

#### Using:

```
using System;
```

#### Cut/Paste example:

```
using System;

namespace ArraySort
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var Color = new String[5];

            Color[0] = "Orange";
            Color[1] = "Blue";
            Color[2] = "Purple";
            Color[3] = "Green";
            Color[4] = "Red";

            Array.Sort(Color); //Error: The type or namespace name 'Sort' does not exist in namespace 'Array'. Are you missing an assembly reference?

            Console.WriteLine ("Colors:");

            foreach(string s in Color)
            {
                Console.WriteLine (s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Output:

```
Colors:
Blue
Green
Orange
Purple
Red

Press any key to continue...
```

Comment: Did I has to do some setup on Monodevelop or something !? 'Cuz still don't working... Tanks !!

Comment: You said you are using Mono 4.2.2, but which version of MonoDevelop are you using?

Comment: MonoDevelop Version 5.10

Comment: Strange, should be fine... if you create a *new* C# `console project` via the built-in template and replace the generated code with the code I posted and change nothing else, does it compile or do you get a build error?

Comment: Yes, it works ! And when I copy and past my code to another project, it works too. But on the original project (that only has that single file on it) didn't work... Really too strange...